# Dans un monde de fantasy, quel est le véritable sens du mot "homme" ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

J'écris une fiction de fantasy et je me pose une question récurrente à laquelle je ne parviens pas à fournir de réponse satisfaisante. L'exemple suivant illustre mon problème :

*Un elfe soldat dit : "Mes hommes sont prêts au combat."*

Ici, il faut comprendre : "Les soldats elfes sous mes ordres sont prêts au combat."

J'ai donc ici un véritable questionnement sur l'utilisation du mot "homme". Ce mot ne désigne pas un humain de sexe masculin dans cette expression. Or, dans un dictionnaire, le mot "homme" serait défini de la façon suivante : "Être humain de sexe masculin".

La question que je me pose donc est : quelle tournure littéraire élégante pourrais-je utiliser pour ne pas dire "homme" dans la réplique de mon soldat elfe ? Je retrouve cette problématique très régulièrement dans des expressions idiomatiques où "homme" ne désigne pas vraiment un "être humain de sexe masculin", mais qui est gênant lorsque prononcé par un personnage non humain.

Avez-vous des idées ?

Merci

Comment: Dans le cas précis que tu donnes  il s'agit de l'emploi du homme pour désigner un individu membre d'une armée, donc soldat, combattant... conviendrait. Dans d'autres situations pourquoi ne pas dire « elfe » tout simplement ?

Comment: C'est une tournure idiomatique, d'où ma question. Quand on dit "mes hommes sont prêts" dans la vie réelle, on peut parler de "subordonnés" pouvant inclure des femmmes.

Answer (score 6):

Le monde réel étant assez pauvre en elfes, gobelins et autres races pensantes qui pourraient utiliser un mot autre qu'"homme", la langue française traite ces minorités fictives d'une façon honteusement ethnocentriste. Un elfe dirait probablement bien "mes hommes sont prêts" sans se poser la question de leur appartenance au genre *homo sapiens sapiens*. On notera d'ailleurs qu'il y a des femmes dans l'armée moderne, mais qu'on dirait quand même "mes hommes" sans distinction de sexe.

De manière générale, la grande majorité des lecteurs sont humains (si quelqu'un a une référence à fournir, qu'il n'hésite pas à éditer). Donc, la plupart des lecteurs, aveuglés par leur statut de majorité privilégiée, ne remarqueront rien de bizarre dans l'usage d'idiomes basés sur "homme".

Dire "mes elfes sont prêts", par exemple, indiquerait que le personnage veut attirer l'attention sur le fait que ce ne sont pas des humains. Selon le contexte ça peut être justifié, sinon ça paraîtra vaguement bizarre. En fait, pour un lecteur humain, lire "mes elfes sont prêts" serait paradoxalement plus inhabituel que lire "mes hommes sont prêts" dans la bouche d'un elfe. Si on n'aime pas cette dernière tournure, on peut aussi utiliser n'importe quoi qui n'est ni "homme", ni "elfe" : "mes soldats sont prêts", "mes troupes sont prêtes"...

Comment: +1, surtout pour "mes/les troupes."

Comment: Je ne suis pas certain que le personnage attire l'attention en disant "mes elfes sont prêts". Il faut penser fantaisie. L'elfe a été élevé par des elfes. Le mot "homme" est donc certainement couramment remplacé par le mot "elfe", et dirait naturellement "elfe". C'est un débat intéressant non ? :)

Comment: Dans l'univers, ça n'attirera pas l'attention de ses auditeurs, qui ont l'habitude d'entendre des elfes parler dans ces termes. Hors de l'univers, ça attirera l'attention du lecteur, qui notera qu'on a altéré une expression idiomatique. C'est naturel du point de vue interne à la fiction, mais forcé du point de vue du dialogue écrivain-lecteur.

Comment: @Random Oui, la question est plus profonde qu'il n'y parait au premier abord ;). A DaWaaaaghBabal : J'ai souvent recours à des périphrases de ce genre, mais je me sens souvent gêné sans pouvoir l'expliquer. Néanmoins, cela reste toujours une solution plus que correcte.

Answer (score 3):

Déjà, le mot *homme* a plusieurs sens, et ce n'est pas « être humain de sexe masculin » qui est pertinent ici. Ce n'est même pas « être humain » (de sexe indifférent), le sens premier du mot. C'est spécifiquement « individu qui est considéré comme dépendant d'un autre, qui est placé sous son autorité » (définition du [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/homme), II.B.5. À noter (ce que ne fait pas le TLF) qu'au moins dans un cadre militaire, « homme » dans ce sens n'est pas forcément masculin.

Il n'y a donc rien de choquant à utiliser le mot *hommes* ici, même s'il ne s'agit pas d'être humains et même s'il ne s'agit pas forcément d'individus masculins.

Ceci étant dit, dans une fiction qui décrit une société dont la langue n'est pas la nôtre, il vaut mieux des fois éviter certains mots qui ont une connotation culturelle. Ceci n'est pas limité au fantastique, mais le problème se pose d'autant plus que la société décrite est éloignée de la nôtre, donc plus pour de la fiction spéculative que pour de la fiction mondaine.

Dans cette phrase en particulier, d'autres mots peuvent convenir, par exemple « mes soldats sont prêts » ou « mes troupes sont prêtes ». (Ces mots ne conviendraient pas forcément si l'organisation de la société était très différente, ou plus encore par exemple s'il ne s'agissait pas d'entités biologiques distinctes.) Mais plus généralement, le terme *homme* est connoté culturellement à notre status d'espèce unique, et peut poser des problèmes si l'on décrit un monde où sont présents des simili-hommes d'un autre type (Néanderthal, espèce ou race génétiquement modifiée, elfes et autres races ou espèces fantastiques, extra-terrestres, intelligences artificielles, etc.).

Choisir le bon mot dans ce cas est une question de style, pas une question de correction ; c'est l'art de l'écrivain qui s'impose. On sort des situations à laquelle notre langue est principalement adaptée. En général, on a besoin de deux termes : un pour désigner l'*homo sapiens* (voire *homo sapiens sapiens*), un autre pour désigner toute espèce ou race considérée comme sentiente et à placer au même niveau que les êtres humains. Suivant le contexte, de nombreuses possibilités existent : humain/sentient, humain/humanoïde, *homo*/humain, etc. (Mais encore une fois, de toute façon, *homme* pour désigner un soldat marche avec à peu près toutes les combinaisons.)

Si le but de l'œuvre n'est pas d'explorer les relations entre espèces sentientes et les limites de l'humain, il vaut mieux rester discret et utiliser du vocabulaire courant, pour ne pas attirer l'attention du lecteur sur des points qui ne sont pas abordés par l'œuvre. De nombreux romans fantastiques peuvent se passer complètement d'un terme englobant elfes, humains et autres races parce que le problème ne se pose pas : un homme est notre race, et si l'on a besoin d'englober tout le monde, on peut utiliser des expressions comme « tout le monde ».

Comment: + 1 Remarquable réponse d'expert, à la fois scientifique, littéraire et philosophique.

Comment: @Gilles Très bonne analyse qui me conforte dans ce que je ressentais sans pour autant avoir su le formuler aussi élégamment que toi. Je continue de méditer sur le sujet...

Answer (score -1):

Ce sont des francophones qui vont te lire, et non pas des elfes.

Tout est donc une question de style,

choisir entre

> Mes hommes sont prêts au combat !

et

> Mes elfes sont prêts au combat !

et le choix qui incombe à l'auteur (toi en l’occurrence).

La deuxième formulation est plus immersive (surtout si il y a un antagonisme avec d'autres races fantastiques).

Comment: Je ne pense pas que « mes elfes sont prêts » soit plus immersif. C'est plutôt le contraire : ça attire l'attention du lecteur sur le fait que ce ne sont pas des humains. Or pour un elfe, avoir des elfes soldats, ce n'est pas remarquable, donc il ne faudrait pas attirer l'attention.

Comment: @Gilles Tout à fait. L'idée est de trouver l'expression la plus "confortable" pour le lecteur, et la plus "logique" pour le locuteur sans pour autant introduire d'incohérence d'un point de vue de l'univers